# Unable to create a manifest resource name for ... when creating and using NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget

Leaqrning how to create a NuGet local package to capture some common code logic and reuse it in other local apps. I did the following:

1) followed the steps to create a NuGet package and seem to have been able to create the package just fine.

2) Created a new project and installed my NuGet local package.

I am now getting this message when I try to build:

> Unable to create a manifest resource name for "MyNuGetProject.resx". Could not find file '[A long path]\MyNuGetProject.cs'.

I have to be doing something wrong with my NuGet package. What could that be and what is the solution?

Comment: Do you have such a file? If don't - do you have it referenced from you project?

Comment: I looked at my file tree and there was a caution symbol. I deleted the file and cleaned the project and it resolved the issue.